# how to configure a2billing to use agi-conf2?

Tags: php, asterisk, ivr, elastix

I am trying to make a2billing use a agi-conf2 , I did a little research and all forums say that it can't be modified through the web , and hardcoded to use 1

Any ideas , I have followed the steps that add a custom extenstions and custome destination and still it doesn't work

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in **asterisk's** dialplan something like

**exten =>_X.,1,AGI(a2billing.php,1); 1 is agi-conf1**

So you have change that in extensions.conf for asterisk.

Comment: yes that is correct I have solved this issue , the solution was to add custom extensions , and custom destinations